# Access POP3 account from JUnit tests

Tags: junit, pop3

I'm looking for a way to access a POP3 account while running a JUnit test. Does anyone know how to do that? I probably need some kind of library for POP3 access I guess.

Comment: I'm intensely curious about why you need to do such a thing!

Comment: I plan on "misusing" JUnit to do some integration testing (and not pure class testing). The functionality I test sends out an email. I simply want to check if this email was received and if it contains the correct content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, actually it is quite simple and not really related to junit. I just use the java.mail.* libs to access the POP3 account.